# G4 S20 vs. G4 P2000

Tags: g-code

Given the Marlin Firmware what is the difference between the following lines of code:

> G4 S20

and

> G4 P2000

Comment: You really ought to be able to look up gcode reference tables online!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the firmware you are using so that people can answer the question for your specific case.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft of course I did prior to asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that ***it depends on the type of firmware*** you are using.

Let us look at the documentation of [`G4`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G4:_Dwell) to find that `G4` is valid for all the listed firmware types:
[image]

> Pause the machine for a period of time.

Furthermore it states that:

> **Parameters**
>
> - Pnnn Time to wait, in milliseconds (In Teacup, P0, wait until all previous moves are finished)
> - Snnn Time to wait, in seconds (Only on Repetier, Marlin, Smoothieware, and RepRapFirmware 1.16 and later)

It clearly shows that the `S` parameter (which defines the pause in seconds) is only supported by a few firmware types. Do note that this documentation may not be up-to-date, so it is best to look into the source code or the users manual of the particular firmware you are using.

---

E.g. if you are using Marlin Firmware, `G4 S20` will pause the machine for 20 seconds while `G4 P2000` will pause the machine for 2000 milliseconds which is 2 seconds. This means that a different time is requested, to have 20 seconds waiting time you could use `G4 P20000`

To answer your question what the ***actual difference*** between the 2 commands is:

- it is **either** 18 seconds of extra waiting time if your firmware supports the `S` parameter, **or**
- a firmware that skips or chokes on the command because it is not supported (that also probably depends on your firmware).

Answer (score 1):

The code `G4` refers to *dwell*. (From what I'm seeing, it can be written as either `G4` or `G04`). `P`is the length of dwell time, usually in milliseconds. The parameter `S` seems to be invalid, because the only inputs are `X` (seconds), `P` (milliseconds), or `U` (undefined). If you have `S20` in your code, it is invalid, whereas `P2000` will cause all axes to remain unmoving for 2 seconds before moving on.

(Note: Not all machines will accept `X` or `U`.)

**EDIT:** This answer is specific to *non-specific* g-code, taken from this [*Source*](https://all3dp.com/g-code-tutorial-3d-printer-gcode-commands/), since the OP did not state any specifics about their firmware type or equipment used.

Comment: See Oscar's answer -- yours is applicable only to certain firmwares.

Comment: I'm curious to know for which firmware(s) this is, could you please add that to your answer.